# dsound.dll crashing my Skype / Windows messenger

Tags: windows-vista, skype, windows-live-messenger, directx

For the last few weeks, I have not been able to start Skype or Windows Messenger ndue to some issue with `dsound.dll`. The error shown (same for both apps) is as follows:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   InPageCoFire
  Error Status Code:    c000009c
  Faulting Media Type:  00000003
  Damaged file name:    dsound.dll
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.768.2
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: fd00
  Additional Information 2: ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160
  Additional Information 3: fd00
  Additional Information 4: ea6f5fe8924aaa756324d57f87834160

Read our privacy statement:
  http://go.Microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409
```

I have tried reinstalling Directx (using the `directx_Jun2010_redist.exe` file from Microsoft.com) but to no avail. I believe this is Directx 9.x but I have not been able to find an exe for Directx 10 which is installed by default on Vista.

The below is my laptop config:

```
OS: Windows Vista Home Basic SP2
Processor: Intel Pentium Dual CPU T3200 @ 2GHz
RAM: 4GB
```

Original Question posted at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828088/dsound-dll-crashing-my-Skype-Windows-messenger).

Comment: Have you tried updating your audio driver from the manufacturer's site? Like a HDA chip from RealTek?

Comment: @Shiki Yes tried that as well but no change!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting long enough for answers, I reinstalled my OS and its now working fine!